# How to upload videos using multi part post entity?

Tags: android

I use this code that i found in some page but I only can upload images from my android application to the server and is working, but when i upload a video(.mp4) its saved as "file" like unknown.

```
public void upload() throws Exception {
    //Url of the server
    String url = "";
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    //Path of the file to be uploaded
    String filepath = "";
    File file = new File(filepath);
    ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file);        

    //Add the data to the multipart entity
    mpEntity.addPart("image", cbFile);
    mpEntity.addPart("name", new StringBody("Test", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    mpEntity.addPart("data", new StringBody("This is test report", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    post.setEntity(mpEntity);
    //Execute the post request
    HttpResponse response1 = client.execute(post);
    //Get the response from the server
    HttpEntity resEntity = response1.getEntity();
    String Response=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
    Log.d("Response:", Response);
    //Generate the array from the response
    JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray("["+Response+"]");
    JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(0);
    //Get the result variables from response 
    String result = (jsonobject.getString("result"));
    String msg = (jsonobject.getString("msg"));
    //Close the connection
    client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
```

There is any way to make this work to upload videos too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not issue with this code works fine for upload videos and images, the problem was i´m missing the file extension in the name, so when the video was uploaded it should be NAME.EXTENSION not only NAME.

NOTE:
For all the people who is trying to upload a large(2MB-10GB) image or video to the server the only solution i found was encode the file in chunks and upload each chunk to the server, from there you only have to encode the chunks again. NO SIZE LIMITATION :)!!!!

Comment: can you please post your final solution because there is no setChunk method on http entity